# What GPARTED alternatives are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, partitioning, gparted

What is a good partitioning tool for Ubuntu 10.X as an alternative to GPARTED?
I haven't been able to find one that is easy to use.
A commercial product is OK if necessary for ease of use.

Comment: what's confusing on gparted? I find it the simplest partition tool I've ever met.

Comment: If I may ask, what makes gparted confusing?  The other tools out there are command line or more confusing

Comment: My advice: If GPartEd is too confusing for you, LETS YOUR HARD DISK AS IT IS! GPartEd is one of the easiest tools to partition your hard drive. And if you haven't got enough computer knowledge to work with GPartEd, you'd probably screw up your hard drive and lose all your data in an instant.

Comment: Gparted for me is easier than the windows versions like Power Quest Partition Magic or the one that comes by default. It is one of the eaiest I have seen and that includes the ones specific made for Seagate, Maxtor and the likes. I really suggest from my experience to give it a chance a learn from it since the rest will be harder or more confusing.

And for your question Gparted IS a good partitioner and easy to use if you give it 5 minutes at least.

Comment: @michael durrant -- what is the use case -- i.e., what are you needing the tool to do?

Comment: Great question.  I wanted to install Ubuntu 11 alongside (another partition) Ubuntu 10  The resolution was actually to just insert a Ubuntu 11 disk and let that give me the choice to install alongside, then resize via a gui (1 slider) and it did it which was great!

Comment: To clarify - I guess the tool is easy if you know partitioning but I do it once in a blue moon and I was getting all sort of issues with mounted volumes, doing it as root, trying cli and gui's.  I guess the lack of (my) knowledge in this area was probably the biggest hurdle.  So many areas to keep proficient in... :)

Comment: You might find it more manageable to have a host system and then install various ubuntu versions with virtualbox. Then you don't have to mess with your partition table or boot manager. It's also easy to backup and restore, etc etc..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Popular terminal-based partition tools are:

1. parted
2. fdisk
3. cfdisk
4. sfdisk

BTW, to list it I just typed `apropos partition`. It's really handy command.

Comment: While those *are* indeed alternatives, I'd hardly consider them "less confusing" than GParted; but to each their own, I guess :)

Comment: i like this answer the best.  I didn't specify less confusing alternatives and although that is implied it also means 'rating' the alternatives.  I like this answer for other users.

Answer (score 15):

`gnome-disk-utility`. This is a personal opinion but I find it to be quite easy than gparted. I think it is installed by default as well.

[image]

Comment: Disk utitlity is nice, but does not provide some options, for example partition resizing. Or does it? For me, it's more "read" tool, just for getting information about my disks.

Comment: @Pavel S.: OTOH, it has a more user-friendly interface for the more common tasks, such as labelling a FS.

Comment: this is now called `gnome-disks`